# How to hook Windows Desktop creation?

Tags: windows, hook, desktop

I use [Sysinternals' Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) in combination with [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/). Unfortunately, Classic Shell only runs automatically for the first desktop.  For desktops 2+, Classic Shell has to be launched manually.

Desktops uses a Windows desktop object for each desktop and a separate Explorer process runs under each to provide the taskbar and start menu.  I was wondering if there was a well-defined way to 'hook' desktop creation and launch an application (Classic Shell)?

Comment: I have no idea, but a little digging yields these, maybe they will help (maybe they won't): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/ca253e22-1ef8-4582-8710-9cd9c89b15c3/ and http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/05/12/did-you-know-3/

Comment: That ought to be signaled by calling WTSRegisterSessionNotification/Ex().  How you get from point A to B is never easy to guess with Russinovich's hacks.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The second looks quite promising.  I'll have to prototype it.

Comment: @Hans Passant: The session callback API is interesting but doesn't yield desktop switch notifications.  (I prototyped it to be sure).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Monitoring the 'WinSta0_DesktopSwitch' event works and should provide a basis for a solution.  Thanks!